# Drupal 7. Подключение файла с функциями

Tags: drupal

Создаю модуль, хочу вынести определенные функции в отдельный файл.

В `modulename.info` добавил:

```
files[] = modulename_handler.inc
```

При обращении к функции (обращение из функции в файле `modulename.module`), объявленной в `modulename_handler.inc` выскакивает ошибка `Call to undefined function`.

Что не так? Заранее, спасибо.

**Update:**
Забыл сказать, кэш я очистил.

Comment: Список подключаемых файлов кэшируется. Вы ведь чистили кэш? :)

Comment: да, исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В описании синтаксиса .info файла модуля Drupal 7 сказано, что вы можете подключать через

```
files[] = modulename_handler.inc
```

только файлы с *классами и интерфейсами* ([ссылка на описание](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#files)).

Как следствие, если вам нужно подключить файл с функциями, то стоит использовать функцию [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7).

Comment: Спасибо. Недосмотрел(